# Creating A Trigger When Insert Is Already Done

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a SQL trigger where I want to update a column("Documents") in my table "Article". I have another table which is "Files" where a FileId is stored. So now i want that FileId in my column "Documents".

I created this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [InsertDocumentId]
ON [dbo].[Files]
FOR UPDATE
AS
INSERT INTO [Article]
    (Documents)
SELECT
    FileId FROM Files LEFT JOIN Article t on Files.ArticleId = t.ArticleId;
GO
```

But this isn't working...

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Why is this tagged as c? There's no c code here.

Comment: "I want to update a column("Documents") in my table "Article"".  You are doing an insert.  This is very confusing.  Sample data and desired results, please.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh Im using MS Sql in visual studio

Comment: I suspect you've oversimplified. We could at least do with some minimal table definitions (just the relevant columns), then some sample data, the insert statement, and what the sample data should like like *after* that insert. Help us help you.

Comment: What is stored in `Documents` field? Comma-separated list of ids?

Comment: Why are you intentionally denormalizing and duplicating data in a relational database? One of the goals of a rdbms is to remove duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to insert table B after insert table A. If that's correct, you can try to use this block of query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [InsertDocumentId] ON [dbo].[Files]
FOR INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO [Article] (Documents)
    SELECT FileId FROM INSERTED f;
GO
```